# Do Laravel Controllers Share Properties between requests?

Tags: php, laravel

Do Laravel controllers share properties between different HTTP requests?
For example if I have the next code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }

    public function show_user_name() {

        return view('user.profile', ['user_name' => $this->user->name]);

    }
}
```

And

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@show_user_name');
```

Won't it be a mess if several users call `/users` simultaneously and `$user` will be the same for all requests?

Comment: Yes it maintains different HTTP request for every different machine or application

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.
You have to use `$this->` to set property of class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
    }

    ...
}
```

And about your question - No Controllers doesn't share properties between each other. (especially when property is private)

But you can use `Auth::user()` anywhere you want. It will be same everywhere but will be different for each request because it depends on user cookies, token and session.

Comment: Thanks) that was just a sample written urgently, I fixed the code